# Why does the NHL not feature red and blue in their logo, as opposed to the other three major sports leagues in the US?

Tags: nfl, mlb, nba, nhl

I was casually browsing the NFL, NBA, MLB and NHL websites today, and realized that even though they are separate governing bodies the websites look quite similar, most notably the scores at the top, as well as the structure of the headers and color palettes.

One big difference I noticed however, is that the NFL, NBA, MLB and even MLS logos feature red and blue (and white), while the NHL logo prominently does not.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no reason for the *Canadian* National Hockey League to have a red, white and blue logo; all the founding teams in the NHL were Canadian, not American. (Oddly, the teams known as the "Original Six" - which do include American teams - are not in fact the founding teams of the NHL)